# Appended button once clicked does nothing

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have done a lot of research for this and found tons of questions on overflow about it but nothing works.

I have a button that is appended onto the page once another element is clicked. Once the button is there the user can then click it to minimize the div back to how it was. There seems to be a lot of questions on this but almost none of them have a checked answer and what the suggestion said to try did not seem to work. I already was using a .on('click') function for it and it still didn't work.

I have a fiddle of the question and if you need more code then just let me know!

**jQuery**

```
function newsArticle() {
    $('.article').on('click', function() {
        $('.article').append('<span class="close">Click to minimize article</span>');
        $('.article').removeClass('article').addClass('fullArticle');
    });

    $('.fullArticle').on('click', '.close', function() {
        $('.fullArticle').removeClass('fullArticle').addClass('article');
        $('.close').hide();
    });
}

newsArticle();
```

**Final Code** (Answer)

```
function newsArticle() {
    $('.article').on('click', function() {
        var self = this;
        var button = $('<span />', {
            'class': 'close',
            text: 'Click to minimize article',
            on: {
                click: function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(self).toggleClass('fullArticle article');
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            }
        });
    if($(event.target).is('.article')) {
        $(this).append(button);
    }
    else if($(event.target).parents().is('.article')) {
        $(this).append(button);
    }
    $(this).removeClass('article').addClass('fullArticle');
    });
}

newsArticle();
```

**I did not copy and paste this code from an answer, I wrote it to retain what I have learned at Stackoverflow today :D**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/sSEX9/2/) (Start)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/sSEX9/13/) (Final)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attaching event (delegation) to `.article` but on click of it you are switching the classes. So the event registered is lost. You need to bind the event (for delegation) to the element (container) that always exists, or just add a common class name to `.article` element which doesn't change and bind the event to that class selector.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsezd/)**

You have other issues in your code as well, on click of close you need to prevent the propagation of click event to the parent `.article` s, otherwise it will bubble up and add one more close button again executing itsparent's click handler.

```
$('.article').on('click', function () {
    $(this).append('<span class="close">Click to minimize article</span>').toggleClass('article fullArticle');
});
   $('.commoncls').on('click', '.close', function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).closest('.commoncls').toggleClass('fullArticle article').end().remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Thank you a million for your explanation, it really helped me out. I'm trying to grasp everything jQuery has to offer and I'm hoping my college will have some good classes for javascript/jQuery.

Comment: I was very interested to find out that you can use toggleClass but it ended up cause a problem for me. You can open and close the article since it is a jquery toggle function and then this will keep appending the button in. Still a good answer!

Comment: @JoshPowell you are welcome... and all the best. Can you replicate the issue in a fiddle...

Comment: I did! I have a start and end fiddle on my question as well as the final code I used.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it :

```
$('.article').on('click', function () {
    var self = this;
    var button = $('<span />', {
        'class': 'close',
        text: 'Click to minimize article',
        on: {
            click: function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(self).removeClass('fullArticle').addClass('article');
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    });
    $(this).removeClass('article').addClass('fullArticle').append(button);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sSEX9/11/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I ended up mixing your answer with PSL answer to make my own! :D Thank you once again!